# Is there anyway to upload an app to reiew on google play console before publish?

Tags: google-console-developer

My app was suspended once, and I believe it was unfair.

I wish to submit my app for another review But before re-publish, because I want to avoid any new suspension may effect on all of my account.

**If I upload my app on Beta or Alpha and leave it in this track for while, Does that put app in testing and review with out risk of consider that as  strike in case google suspend my app again with out review context?**

update -------------------------------

I emailed google play developer support for this issue, and i get the following answer
"Kindly note that every app has to be compliant with the Play policy once it is submitted."